# Are there conditions under which the subtrees produced by spectral (Fiedler vector) bisection are disconnected?

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to partition an undirected tree into two subtrees, where each subtree is connected. My understanding was that this could be done using the Fiedler vector as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition#Fiedler_eigenvalue_and_eigenvector). However, when I follow this process the resulting subtrees are not connected.

The code I used to implement the bisection is below, and the tree which fails to bisect is defined [here](https://gist.github.com/hinnefe2/6ed2a428e4db0d385be83428cdd57ab0).

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import compress

g = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(broken_g)

def split_graph(graph):
    """Split a graph into two pieces using the Fiedler vector.

    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition#Fiedler_eigenvalue_and_eigenvector
    """

    assert nx.is_connected(graph), 'must pass connected graph'

    fiedler_vec = nx.fiedler_vector(graph, normalized=True, weight=False)

    mask_a = fiedler_vec > 0
    mask_b = ~ mask_a

    subgraph_a_nodes = compress(graph.nodes(), mask_a)
    subgraph_b_nodes = compress(graph.nodes(), mask_b)

    subgraph_a = graph.subgraph(subgraph_a_nodes)
    subgraph_b = graph.subgraph(subgraph_b_nodes)

    assert nx.is_connected(subgraph_a) and nx.is_connected(subgraph_b), 'split did not produce connected subgraphs'

    return [subgraph_a, subgraph_b]

split_graph(g)
```

When I run this neither of the resulting subtrees is connected - each subtree has one or two large connected components and several isolated nodes. Plotting the values of the Fiedler vector and identifying the isolated nodes looks like this:

[image]

What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

One characteristic of a tree is that there is only one path between each pair of vertexes in the tree. As a result, When an edge is cut, the vertexes that were on that edge are no longer connected, since that was their only path. Since connectivity is commutative, every vertex on one side of the cut is disconnected from every vertex on the other side of the cut. The result is that you always partition a tree into two connected subtrees when ever you cut a single edge. Looking at that wikipedia page, it looks like using spectral bisection could result in solutions that cut multiple edges. Basically any bisection that cuts more than 1 edge will produce more than 2 connected subtrees.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I should have made this more clear in the question, but my understanding is that this partitioning method is supposed to guarantee connected components (for example, the abstract of [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.592.1730&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper claims so).

I'm wondering if there are conditions under which that theorem doesn't apply, or whether something in my implementation is wrong. Thanks!